# Use of malloc with structs

Tags: c, struct, malloc

Been reading through a few threads on here and watching some YouTube videos and struggling to get malloc to 'click' when it comes to this task I am trying to do.

Apologies in advance if this is a duplicate but I couldn't find a clear answer on another thread.

Say I have a struct for defining personal data declared as follows:

```
    struct strDate
    {
        int     nDay;
        int     nMonth;
        int     nYear;
    };

    struct  strTime
    {
        int     nSeconds;
        int     nMinutes;
        int     nHours;
    };

    struct strName
    {
        char            arcTitle[10];
        char            arcFirstName[50];
        char            arcMiddleName[50];
        char            arcSurname[50];
    };

    struct strPerson
    {
        struct strDate  strDOB;
        struct strName  strFullName;
        struct strTime  strStartTime;
        struct strDate  strStartDate;
        char            arcJobTitle[31];
        int             nEmployeeNumber;
    };
```

My current understanding of Malloc is as follows:

Malloc can be used to determine how much memory is needed to store a value (depending on type and size etc.). This can be applied to create link lists by placing pointers at the end of each value that point to the next value in the list.

How would I go about applying malloc to my code?

Say if I had an array of structs as follows:

```
    // Variable Declarations
    struct strPerson    Person[5];
```

Say I want to start out by filling the data with blank placeholders (to prevent garbage values being pulled from memory) and later populate a struct with data, how would I ensure it is using an appropriate amount of memory with malloc?

I am currently doing it this without malloc but I imagine this is inefficient, as it could be possible to exceed one of the string array lengths. Anyway:

```
// Blank Data
for (nCount = 0; nCount < 5; nCount++)
        fnDefaultBlankPersonData(&Person[nCount]); // fills all structures with blank data to avoid unusual values pulled from memory


// Real Data
fnPopulatePersonData(&Person[0], "Mr", "PlaceholderFirst", "PlaceholderMiddle", "PlaceholderLast", "PlaceholderJobTitle", 1, 1, 1980, 1, 9, 2001, 8, 0, 0, 6);
```

Mainly focusing on that 'real data' population above: how do I ensure the struct is sized appropriately to fit the data, and can resize if I were to rerun the function to repopulate it?

(the two functions above simply assign values to the struct with = and strcpy() )

Answer (score 4):

The `malloc` function is *not* used to determine how much memory is needed to store a value.  The `sizeof` operator does that.

What `malloc` does is dynamically allocate a given amount of memory for your program's  use.

In your use case, it doesn't look like you need `malloc`.  You're looking to clear out a section of memory so it contains known values.  If you want all bytes to contain 0 you can use the `memset` function for that:

```
for (nCount = 0; nCount < 5; nCount++)
    memset(&Person[nCount], 0, sizeof(Person[nCount]);
```

Better yet, you can do this for the whole array at once instead of once for each element:

```
memset(Person, 0, sizeof(Person);
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip regarding memset for blanking data. However for the second part of the second code snippet I am populating the struct with data- but what if say, one of the string values I am attempting to insert exceeds the size it has been defined as?

Comment: @CharlieWebb If you do that you invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  So your code needs to know the size of the buffer (easy in this case since the buffer is a fixed size) and not exceed it.

Comment: `memset(&Person[nCount], 0, sizeof(Person[nCount]);` is unlikely to be correct. It seems that you are zeroing space *after* the allocated memory.

Comment: @user694733 When you declare a variable, it's contents are unspecified if it is not initialized.  So if you want the contents to be known you need to set them in some way, such as using memset.

Comment: I know, that's not what I meant. Using `nCount` in this context smells like a mistake. It's more likely that you should have written `memset(Person, 0, sizeof Person);`

Comment: @user694733 Yes, you are correct.  I was looking at it from the perspective of the function `fnDefaultBlankPersonData` which presumably clears out one element at a time.  I've updated to clear the whole array instead.

Comment: I misunderstood your original answer then. Anyway, it's clear now. +1